# Do not show the CSS when downloading Node.js on Heroku

Tags: css, node.js, heroku

Not so long ago I began to study programming. I created an application based on Node.js. When uploading to the Heroku, all styles disappear. [Here](https://look4cry.herokuapp.com/) is the site itself. I attach a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q07pV.jpg) of the error from the browser. When running locally, styles are applied correctly
that's how it should look [like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktm1E.jpg)

I ask you to help, I have already installed all the Internet.
My code on GitHub: https://github.com/eazykun/look4cry

```
doctype 5
html
 head
  meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, inital-scale=1.0')
  title= title
  link(rel='stylesheet',href='/bootstrap/css/amelia.bootstrap.css')
  link(rel='stylesheet',href='/stylesheets/style.css')
 body
   .navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top
    .container
     .navbar-header
        a.navbar-brand(href='/') Look4cry
        button.navbar-toggle(type='button', data-toggle='collapse'
     data-target='#navbar-main')
          span.icon-bar
          span.icon-bar
          span.icon-bar
     #navbar-main.navbar-collapse.collapse
       ul.nav.navbar-nav
         li
           a(href='/about/') О нас              


.container
 block content

footer
 .row
  .col-xs-12
   small &copy; Max Sheps 2018  
 script(src='/javascripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js')
 script(src='/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: You're getting 404 requests to your external stylesheets and scripts - either you haven't uploaded the CSS and JavaScript files, or you've uploaded them to the wrong folder. Either way, your code can't find the files in the folder it's told to look for them in. Because you are prefixing with `/`, your script looks for the folders at **root** level. As such, you need to have the layout `[root]/bootstrap/css/amelia.bootstrap.css` and so on.

Comment: The file /bootstrap/css/amelia.bootstrap.css is accessible using uppercase B in folder name https://look4cry.herokuapp.com/Bootstrap/css/amelia.bootstrap.css so just rename the folder `Bootstrap` to `bootstrap` and everything will work

Comment: it works! thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!